# Remove jqGrid scrollbar to make the bottom pager move down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jqgrid, scrollbar

I've been updating the jqGrid and jQuery versions on my application and I noticed that instead of having the bottom pager of the grid going down when the number of rows increased, now the pager doesn't move down anymore, it is fixed, and a scrollbar appears to navigate up and down.

What I'd like to know is: what is responsible for that, and how to edit it?

I've tried the option

```
scroll : true
```

but I'd really like to have a full display of the rows and use my navigator's scrollbar to move up and down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found where the problem was coming from, in the  tag of my index, my JavaScript and CSS includes were :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
```

I replaced it with :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.4/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.4/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
```

I guess the problem was that I had a `jqgrid.min.js` with a `jqgrid.css` but I am not 100% sure about that, nevertheless now my bottom pager moves all the way down my navigator page when displaying  all rows.